# C - return different value types from function

Tags: c

I wrote the following function to convert a string to double:

```
double convert_to_double(char *str){
    char *remaining_str;
    double number;

    number = strtod(str, &remaining_str);

    /* we want to get only a double as parameter  */
    if ( strlen(remaining_str) > 0 ) {
        return NULL; // something like this
    }

    return number;
}
```

I want to make sure the parameter that the function accepts, containing only a double. For example:

- `"Hello world 20.12312"` is not a good.
- `"20.12312"` is OK.

In the first example I want to return NULL, "false", anything that is not a double, So the function that calls `convert_to_double` will know there's something wrong with the string.

Is there any elegant way to do this? Or in that case `strtod` is not a good solution and I need to think about something else?

Comment: BTW: what you do here is not "casting" but "converting". And you cannot return `NULL` if the return value is not a pointer.

Comment: The macro `NULL` is for pointers, not for values. Except for null pointers, there is no way in C to indicate "no value". You have to figure out some other way, like passing an extra `double *` argument that is a pointer to the variable to assign to, and then return a boolean true or false to indicate success or failure.

Comment: For floating point, there would be `NaN`s. But it is an XY problem. As you already use `strtod`, your function is pretty useless and not a good idea either, because you cannot continue properly, reading further input (you might not want to **now**, but wait for the next few lessons). Did you read the documentation of `strtod`? Dide you understand it? Did you think about the (positive) implications of how the function arguments are handled?

Comment: Note that `strtod()` will skip leading white space; is there a good reason to reject trailing white space?  If you don't want leading white space, you'll have to check for that before calling `strtod()`; if you want to allow trailing white space, you'll need a different post-conversion check.  As it stands, your code will accept an empty string as valid, or an all blank string.  You should consider `int convert_to_double(const char *string, double *value)` which returns 0 on success and some appropriate error indication on failure.

Comment: Also, to use `strtod()` accurately, you have to do things like set `errno` to `0` before calling it and check the return value and `errno`.  The POSIX specification for [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) says: _Since 0 is returned on error and is also a valid return on success, an application wishing to check for error situations should set `errno` to 0, then call `strtod()` […] then check `errno`._  There are also other error return values (±HUGE_VAL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can only return one type. If you want to return both a result and a success indicator, you can return one of them through a pointer.

```
int cast_to_double(char *str, double *result) {
    char *remaining_str;
    double number;

    number = strtod(str, &remaining_str);

    /* we want to get only a double as parameter  */
    if ( strlen(remaining_str) > 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    *result = number;
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
double somevar;
char *input;
if (!cast_to_double(input, &somevar)) {
    printf("Bad input %s\n", input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return NULL if the return value is not a pointer.

**Solution 1**

```
double convert_to_double(char *str, int *ok){
    char *remaining_str;
    double number;

    number = strtod(str, &remaining_str);

    /* we want to get only a double as parameter  */
    if ( strlen(remaining_str) > 0 ) {
        *ok = 0;   // conversion failed
        return 0;  // we must return something
    }

    *ok = 1;       // conversion OK
    return number;
}
```

Call like this:

```
int ok;
double value = convert_to_double(str, &ok);
if (!ok)
{
  // argh! COnversion failed
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
int convert_to_double(char *str, double *number){
    char *remaining_str;

    *number = strtod(str, &remaining_str);

    /* we want to get only a double as parameter  */
    if ( strlen(remaining_str) > 0 ) {
        return 0;  // converion failed
    }

    return 1;   // conversion OK
}
```

Call like this:

```
double value;
if (!convert_to_double(str, &value))
{
  // argh! COnversion failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a `double`, not `NULL` which is a `void *` (`((void*)0)`).

A function only returns 1 data of a fixed type. To process the way you want, you could pass a pointer parameter to check the conversion process like this :

```
bool success = true;
double value = cast_to_double("My double : 2.3", &success);
if (success)
    ...
```

Your function could then modify the `bool *success` value. The reverse way could be better though :

```
double value = 0;
if (! cast_to_double("My double 3.2", &value))
    // Error
```

This way you can check the return value and get the string as a double like you would.